# Fetching data from different site with php

Tags: php, curl

I am Trying to use the following example to fetch data of the

http://www.dsebd.org/dseX_share.php this Site

but i was finding some error can anyone help ??

```
$content = file_get_contents("http://www.cba.am/am/SitePages/Default.aspx");
preg_match('#<b>USD</b>(.*)<em class="w_50">([0-9\.]*)</em><em class="w_50">([0-9\.]*)</em>#Uis', $content, $USDmatch);
preg_match('#<b>EUR</b>(.*)<em class="w_50">([0-9\.]*)</em><em class="w_50">([0-9\.]*)</em>#Uis', $content, $EURmatch);
preg_match('#<b>GBP</b>(.*)<em class="w_50">([0-9\.]*)</em><em class="w_50">([0-9\.]*)</em>#Uis', $content, $GBPmatch);
$eur = $EURmatch[3];
$usd = $USDmatch[3];
$gbp = $GBPmatch[3];
echo "EUR: $eur USD: $usd GBP: $gbp";
```

Comment: Are you aware that most likely you're violating their [ToS](http://www.dsebd.org/termsacond.htm)? Some of their terms are really funny though: "*You may not create a link to this website* from another website or document without Dhaka Stock Exchange Limited's prior written consent." --- this lold me much

Comment: I wasn't acctually building a new site i am doing it for an application  part

Comment: "This website contains material which is owned by or licensed or copyright to us. This material includes, but is not limited to, the design, layout, look, appearance, graphs, trade data, live ticker and graphics. Reproduction is prohibited other than in accordance with the copyright notice, which forms part of these terms and conditions and unless prior permission is obtained."